# Handle the streambuilder if there is no result

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the script to build a gridview use `StreamBuilder` here is my script

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.categoryName),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Divider(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Flexible(
                  child:StreamBuilder<List<Products>>(
                stream: _productController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return errMess(context, "Failed to fetch data");
                  } else {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      if (snapshot.data.length > 0) {
                        return ProductList(categoryId: widget.categoryId,category: snapshot.data,onLoad: (categoryId, limit, offset) {
                          loadProduct(categoryId, limit, offset);
                        }
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
                      }
                    } else {
                      return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
                    }
                  }
                },
              )),
              Divider(
                height: 25.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
        )
    );
  }
```

there is no error on my code, but I have a problem about fetching the data when the stream return `null` my data that inside the `GridView` that show up before the `null` result is gone.

I know the `StreamBuilder` populating a `Container` because the result is `null`. So how can I handle this? I want to keep showing my `GridView`

Comment: You can have mock data that initially fills the grid view and have a boolean set to false. If the data returned is null, you can call set state on the boolean value to true and keep showing the mock data, or a message saying there is an error

Answer (score 0):

StreamBuilder has a property call initialData that can be used to create the initial snapshot. In you code try to set it to an empty list of Products and remove the condition of snapshot.hasData and snapshot.data.length > 0 to render a ProductList, witch i suppose is the grid, with no data on it until the stream load the real products.

Something like :

```
          Flexible(
              child:StreamBuilder<List<Products>>(
            initialData: <Products>[],
            stream: _productController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return errMess(context, "Failed to fetch data");
              } else {
                    return ProductList(categoryId: widget.categoryId,category: snapshot.data,onLoad: (categoryId, limit, offset) {
                      loadProduct(categoryId, limit, offset);
                    }
                    );
                  } 
              }
            },
          )),
```

Hope it helps!